# Download CSV from SQL query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv, mysql-workbench

When I run the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM selecteddb.mytable 
where time between "2018-08-06 00:00:00" and "2018-08-13 00:00:00"
INTO outfile "~/stats.csv" 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I get the below error:

```
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

But when I run just the query without `outfile` it runs just fine.

I'm using MySQL Workbench and Mac to run the query.

Comment: Assuming you in fact logged in to workbench and ran the query, my guess is that MySQL doesn't have write permissions at `~/stats.csv`.  So, you should look into this.

Comment: It looks you're facing with permissions issue.

Comment: You know that this will create the file in the host right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `admin` user doesn't have [FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege. You can grant the permission and it will work.

```
GRANT FILE ON * . * TO 'admin'@'%';
```

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' form of SELECT writes the
>   selected rows to a file. The file is created on the server host, so
>   you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax. file_name cannot
>   be an existing file, which among other things prevents files such as
>   /etc/passwd and database tables from being destroyed. The
>   character_set_filesystem system variable controls the interpretation
>   of the file name.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

=========================================================

Also note that mysql server needs to have write permission on the path you provide.

> The FILE privilege also enables the user to create new files in any
>   directory where the MySQL server has write access. This includes the
>   server's data directory containing the files that implement the
>   privilege tables.

If you execute your query as:

```
SELECT * FROM selecteddb.mytable ..... INTO outfile "~/stats.csv";
```

This will try to create the file in the home directory. If you omit the paths and leave only the file name, it will be created in the Mysql's data directory. (`/var/lib/mysql` in my Ubuntu machine).

So this should work without any problem.

```
SELECT * FROM selecteddb.mytable ..... INTO outfile "stats.csv";
```

Hope it helps!!